# OpenGL prevent Texture to get influenced by alpha

Tags: opengl, textures, transparency, alpha

I am using glColor4f to select a drawing color. glVertex3f is used to set figure's vertices.
With glTexCoord2f I can map my texture on the figure.

So my situation is that I have textures with totally transparent areas so that I can see through it. Figure's sides have colors using transparency. By mapping a texture on such a figure the texture also looks transparent.

Is there a way to prevent the texture being transparent in OpenGL?

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you mean. At first I thought you were talking about pre-multiplied alpha, but this does not appear to be the case. In GL3 you have access to shaders, so you can swizzle your texture and vertex color anyway you like (e.g. `texture (...).rgb * vtx_color.a`).

Comment: "Is there a way to do this with OpenGL 3(+)?" well, as a start, you can't use `glColor*()` in OpenGL 3.0+

Comment: Actually, you can. Only core profiles have eliminated the functions that set "current" color. It really depends on the platform (OS X, for instance does not support compatibility profiles), but I tend to assume that people are referring to a compatibility profile unless they explicitly state core somewhere.

Comment: Actually, I think the OP is talking about the `ALPHA_TEST` - at least the wording "totally transparent areas" suggests as much. The alpha-test is now usually applies by using fragment shaders `discard` when the alpha value of the texel at the specified tex coordinate falls below a certain threshold. To achieve something similar with the fixed function pipeline, check out `glAlphaFunc` and `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)`.